# How to fix "TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined" | discord.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, discord.js

## I'm trying to make a giveaway command for my discord bot.

Everything works perfectly, except for the end part where it shows who won the giveaway. I'm trying to convert the `winners` array into a string so that I can send a message that shows the winner(s). I spent an entire day trying to fix this (I'm not too good at programming, to be honest) to no avail. **Please help!**

```js
message.channel.send(" **GIVEAWAY** ").then(() => {
  message.channel.send(Embed).then((gMessage) => {
    gMessage.react("");
    setTimeout(function() {
      var peopleReacted = gMessage.reactions.cache.get("").users;
      var winners = [];

      // Checks if fewer people reacted than the the winner count allows users to win
      if (peopleReacted.length <= args[2]) {
        winners = peopleReacted;
      } else {
        // Gets as many random users from the peopleReacted as the winner count allows users to win
        for (var i = 0; i < args[2]; i++) {
          var index = Math.floor(
            Math.random() * peopleReacted.length
          );
          winners.push(peopleReacted[index]);
          // After adding a user to winners, remove that item from the array to prevent them from winning multiple times
          peopleReacted.cache.array().splice(index, 1);
        }
      }

      var winnerMsg = "User(s) ";
      for (var i = 0; i < winners.length; i++) {
        // Add each winner to the winnerMsg
        winnerMsg += winners[i].toString() + ", ";
      }

      var haveHas;
      if (winners.length === 1) {
        haveHas = "has";
      } else {
        haveHas = "have";
      }
      message.channel.send(`${winnerMsg} ${haveHas} won ${msgArgs}`);
    }, time * (60 * 1000));
  });
});
```

If it helps, all of my bot's code can be found [here](https://github.com/ControlFreak707/RoboLiam).

Comment: Try debugging. Clearly, `winners[i]` is null at some point and therefore `null.toString()` will throw an exception

Comment: add `console.log(winners[i])` and `console.log(winners)` before you try to convert it to a string and let us know what it returns.

Comment: @Aci I did what you said. For `console.log(winners[i])` I got `undefined` and for `console.log(winners)` I got `[ undefined ]`. I did not react to the giveaway when logging and stated that there could only be one winner. (The bot is the only one that reacted.)

Comment: I uh... Still need help with this.

Answer (score 0):

`gMessage.reactions.cache.get("").users` is probably the problem, since `gMessage.reactions.cache.get("")` returns a collection, it does not have an users property (= it is `undefined`). 
If you want the reaction as an array, simply use `gMessage.reactions.cache.get("").array()`, this will return an array with the user objects (Note: Those are not "normal" user objects, but `ReactionUserManager`, you can find more on these in the docs https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ReactionUserManager)

Comment: Got an error `TypeError: gMessage.reactions.cache.get(...).array is not a function` :\

Comment: @LiamTheSnowLeopard which version of Discord.js are you using? The docs are for v12 and quite a lot changed from v11, in my old bot (using v11.5.1 or so), I had to do `msg.reactions.first().users.array()` for example. You can view your version in the package.json file

Comment: I am using discord.js **v12.1.1** for my bot. If my version is the problem, would you happen to know a substitute to `.array()`?

Comment: Nvm, I found a function that sounds extremely similar to `.array()`, it is `.toArray()`. I am going to test it out later today.

Comment: I got an error saying that `.toArray()` is not a function... well, It was worth a shot lol